# Accessing value from associative array

Tags: array

Here's my code:

```
        $args = array(
            'child_of' => $CurrentPage
            );
        $children = get_pages( $args );
        foreach ($children as $child) {
            foreach ($child as $key => $value) {
            echo $key['post_title'];
            }
        };
```

And output:

```
IpppppppcppptpppppgmppcfIpppppppcppptpppppgmppcf
```

The output appears to be the first character of the $key, repeated over both children.

ID , post_author , post_date , post_date_gmt , post_content , post_title , etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're doing one to many loops.  What you want to be doing is this:

```
$args = array(
    'child_of' => $CurrentPage
);
$children = get_pages( $args );
foreach ($children as $key => $value) {
    echo $key['post_title'];
};
```

Or you could also:

```
$args = array(
    'child_of' => $CurrentPage
);
$children = get_pages( $args );
foreach ($children as $child) {
    echo $child->post_title;
};
```

It's entirely up to you, but since you already know what elements each `$child` has, why not stick to the same syntax as used in the [`get_pages()` Codex article](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_pages)?